# ¿Como Emular retorno de tipos desde interfaz en PHP?

Tags: php

Tengo que obtener cierta información de los modelos de la base de datos. El problema es que todos los modelos (que describen a las tablas) son diferentes. La información de los modelos debe mostrase en una agenda, por lo tanto necesito una misma estructura [titulo, fecha desde, fecha hasta, tipo de evento, etc] para todos los modelos.

Entonces mi idea es crear una interfaz que obligue a los modelos a tener ciertas características. Un modelo de ejemplo es este:

**Modelo que representa a una tabla de la base de datos**

```
class EventsType1 extends Model {
    // metodos y atributos del modelo 1
}

class EventsType2 extends Model {
    // metodos y atributos del modelo 2
}
```

**Interfaz que quiero que los modelos implementen:**

```
interface IScheludable {
    // permite obtener los eventos en el formato que la agenda necesita
    public function getEvents(fromDate, toDate);
}
```

Ahora puedo lograr que los modelos tengan las funciones que necesito que implementen sin importar el tipo de evento, de una forma similar a esta:

```
class EventsType2 extends Model implements IScheludable {
    // metodos y atributos del modelo 2
    public function getEvents(fromDate, toDate){
        // return eventos desde el modelo
    }
}
```

PERO, no puedo lograr que la interfaz también obligue a que el modelo entregue una estructura especifica de datos para la agenda. Este es un ejemplo de la estructura que necesito (y que la agenda devuelve al cliente web):

```
class Event {
    public $title;
    public $dateFrom;
    public $dateTo;
    public $eventColor;

    function __construct($title, $date, $someArgs) {
        // set params
    }
    //etc
}
```

Entiendo que en PHP 7 se puede definir el tipo de retorno, pero no uso PHP 7 en este proyecto. Entonces necesito que la interfaz obligue a las clases que la implementan a devolver cierta estructura especificada, de lo contrario la interfaz no tiene mucho sentido. Considerar lo siguiente:

```
class EventsType2 extends Model implements IScheludable {
    // metodos y atributos del modelo 2
    public function getEvents(fromDate, toDate){
        // Operaciones
        return new Event('Evento1', '1-2-2015', $otherArgs);
    }
}
```

Esto también es válido:

```
class EventsType2 extends Model implements IScheludable {
    // metodos y atributos del modelo 2
    public function getEvents(fromDate, toDate){
        // Operaciones
        return new AnyClass(); // <- Justamente esto quiero que no ocurra
    }
}
```

[Otro ejemplo en Php Sandbox](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/27458b853d2c9610a76a79662f86cfaf24b833bd)

Comment: Quieres que todos los modelos (de distintas entidades) entreguen una clase homogénea cuando ¿Al serializar? ¿Como resultado de un método? ¿No te sirve que la salida sea un array asociativo o un stdClass?

Comment: Sí, pero la estructura que quieres devolver no tiene constructor. ¿Quieres devolver una defiición de clase o una instancia de clase?

Comment: Y cómo esperas que devuelvan? Llamando a un mismo método en todas las entidades? Algo asi como "getEvento"?

Comment: Claro. En java es tan simple como declarar en la interfaz una funcion `Evento getEvento(Date desde, Date hasta)` entonces las implementaciones deben por olbligacion devolver tipos Eventos. Pero en php <7 no se pueden declarar tipos  :(

Answer (score 1):

Supongamos que todos los modelos del ORM, que representan a distintas tablas, tienen de alguna manera el equivalente de `$dateFrom` y `$dateTo` (estoy simplificando tu ejemplo para simplificarme la vida). Tú necesitas que todos los modelos sean capaces de devolver una instancia de la clase `Evento` que tiene campos predefinidos.

```
class Event {
    public $dateFrom;
    public $dateTo;
}
```

Sean EventType1 y EventsType2 dos modelos distintos que representan a dos tablas distintas, con atributos:

```
class EventsType1 extends Model {
    public $time_ini;
    public $time_fin;
}

class EventsType2 extends Model {
    public $desde;
    public $hasta;
}
```

Sería cosa de agregarle a cada modelo un método `getEvent` que usando sus propiedades devolviera una instancia válida de Event. Y esto implica customizar el método en cada entidad.

```
class EventsType1 extends Model {
    public $time_ini;
    public $time_fin;

    public function getEvent() {
       return new Event($this->time_ini, $this->time_fin);
    }
}

class EventsType2 extends Model {
    public $desde;
    public $hasta;

    public function getEvent() {
       return new Event($this->desde, $this->hasta);
    }
}
```

Con eso cada entit, sin importar cómo se llamen sus propiedades, es capaz de exportar un evento en el formato esperado.

Comment: Ese es exactamente mi problema :( . Para implementar la Interface uso `implements` de esta forma `class EventsType2 extends Model implements   IScheludable` lo que me obliga a implementar los metodos. PERO no me obliga a que los metodos que se implementan devuelvan `return new Event($this->desde, $this->hasta);`. De hecho podría ser `return new OtroClase ()` y sería válido

Comment: por eso, tendrás que customizar ese método caso a caso, porque la interfaz no obliga a nada en ese aspecto

Comment: Claro, me preguntaba si existe una forma de hacerlo, pero parece que la solucion solo es usar PHP7 o dejar a juicio del programador el devolver el tipo correcto :(

Answer (score 0):

para realizar este tipo de problemas, podrías utilizar [Traits](http://php.net/manual/es/language.oop5.traits.php).

Bastaría con que implementases un `Trait` que implementara esta lógica de retornar un evento:

```
trait EventTrait {
  public function getEvents($from, $to) {
    return new Event (...);
  } 
}
```

y luego en tus modelos:

```
class EventsType1 extends Model {
  // metodos y atributos del modelo 1
  use EventTrait;
}

class EventsType2 extends Model {
  // metodos y atributos del modelo 2
  use EventTrait;
}
```

En general, los `traits`(rasgos en inglés) sirven para reutilizar código donde la herencia del lenguaje es simple (no multiherencia). Gracias a esto, puede definir externamente funcionalidad común para varias clases y luego hacer que nuevas clases utilicen estos 'rasgos'.

espero haber ayudado

saludos

Comment: Ahora que lo pienso, si bastan $from y $to para instanciar un Event, daría lo mismo hacer un método estático en el trait.